# .delay() ignored after .animate()

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, delay

I have number of divs, which should expand after each other.
The expand animation of each div has to be delayed until the animation of the div before is completed. This works as expected.

After the animation of each step, I want to be possible to delay the animation of the next div a little bit further. My problem is, that jQuery ignores the delay after the animation completely.
Is there anything wrong in calling `.delay()` after `.animate()`?

This is my current code:

```
$('div').each(function(index){
    $(this).delay(index*$stepspeed).animate({height: $stepheight[index]}, $stepspeed).delay((index+1)*$stepdelay+$startdelay);
});
```

---

## Answer

I have solved it by using `if` to skip the delay in the first `div`.
This is the code I have used:

```
$('div').each(function(index){
    if(index == 0) {$(this).delay($fadespeed).animate({height: $stepheight[index]}, $stepspeed);} //No delay for the first div
    else {$(this).delay($fadespeed+index*$stepspeed+(index+1)*$stepdelay+$startdelay).animate({height: $stepheight[index]}, $stepspeed);}
});
```

Comment: The delay at the end has nothing to do with delaying the next element in the loop, just increase `$stepspeed`.

Comment: So there is no way to delay the next element of the loop?
Adding a delay in before the animationm would require to check, if the current div is the first div in the loop. It wouldn’t be a problem, but it I thought it would add unnecessary code …

Comment: There's always timeouts ?

Comment: I tried to add a `setTimeout` to the end of the element, but that only gave me errors … I went with If/Else for now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a solution that is a lot simpler but here is my solution ([**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LkWMs/6/)).

Build a function which is called for each div after a little timeout in a loop like fashion:

```
$(function() {
    var el = $('div');
    lp(0);
    function lp(count){
        $(el.get(count)).animate({height: '200px'}, {duration: 500, queue: true, complete: function() {
            setTimeout(function(){
                if(count != el.length-1)
                {
                    count++;
                    lp(count);
                }
            }, 500);
        }});
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I haven’t tested that one, since I have found a solution using If/Else-statements, but I will look into it. Maybe yours is easier.